# Trigger to connect one database to an other database

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, database-trigger

I'm asking if there's any trigger which is able to connect a postgreSql database  to an other database (SQLServer).

However, i need to connect to 2 databases in my application but the SQLServer database is a very big database and i need just 2 tables from it. That's why i'm thinking about creating a trigger in my first database (postgreSQL)

Is this possible ? If yes, how to do it, please?

Thank you! =D

Comment: A trigger can't "connect" anything. Are you trying to access data stored in a Postgres database from a SQL Server database? Or the other way round?

Comment: I'm trying to access data stored in SQL Server database  from  Postgres database.I'm working with Spring Boot also. I don't know if this can help

Comment: You could try a foreign data wrapper for SQL Server:  https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw